# Cast a dynamic value onto specific type derived from a string representation of the type as retrieved using .GetType()

Tags: c#, json.net

Not sure how I did on the vernacular of the ? but my issue is I have a dynamic property being serialized via Json.net. For reasons I will not get into, Json.net's built in type handling will not due. Now with my property being stored in Json is also a string representation of the type, for example `System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` for an int. How can I use that to cast type of dynamic into the specified type?

Comment: Are the types you need to support known beforehand? Or can the types be anything, even types you're can't anticipate during development?

Comment: they are known at runtime, but not compile time because some of them reside in plugins, but the plugins will be loaded and initialized prior to casting so the type should exist and be valid.

Comment: also if possible I would like it to be version/culture and key token independent, IE a string from .net 3.0 should be interchangeable with a string in .net4.5 so I should find out how to omit that from my type string aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how extensive you want to get. There are a few options.

Option 1:

An easy one, if the number of possible types is known and not too extensive would be the following:

Use the type string to pick which type to cast to using an if/switch

```
var typeString = "System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";

var typeName = GetTypeName(typeString);

switch(typeName)
{
   case "System.Int32":
      //code to convert the dynamic representation into an int (e.g. Int32.TryParse(theTypeAsString) );
      break;
   case "System.Double":
      //code to convert the dynamic representation into an double (e.g. Double.TryParse(theTypeAsString) );
      break;
   ...
   default:
      throw new InvalidOperationException("The type provided is unknown.");
}
```

The above is just pseudo-code. But something like that you could try.

Option 2:

After reading your comment, a more complex way, but probably what you'll have to do, is to use reflection.

First you'll want to use the type information to do a runtime type lookup with something like:

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
```

Once you have the type object, you now have the information you need to start the cast. I'm assuming you just need to cast, not to deserialize. If you just need to cast, then you can probably use something like

```
var destinationObject = Convert.ChangeType(dynamicProperty, type);
```

You can also use that type object to call methods via reflection.

```
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("SomeMethodBlah", 
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, 
                ...);
mi.Invoke(...);
```

I think option 2 is probably the better option for you.

Comment: It operates on the assumption that I know the various types beforehand, not horrible, but I would like to future proof it a tad incase people introduce custom class object in the future and store them in the dynamic property

Comment: looking for something like `var obj = (GetTypeFromString(mystring))MyDunamicObj; ` or `var obj = (MyDunamicObj as GetTypeFromString(mystring)); `

Comment: Yeah, wrote that before your answer. Just added an option 2 which I think is better for your case, if I understand your use case.

Comment: That looks perfect, `ChangeType` is exactly what I was looking for! Will GetType work if all I have is "System.Int32, mscorlib" so it is a little more flexible?

Comment: I would look through the overloads. The thing is, there can't be ambiguity, otherwise the runtime isn't sure what to pick, but if you look through the overloads (there are several of them) there might be something closer to what you want.

Comment: Looking through the overloads, I'm not sure if you can do that. I think you have to provide the additional assembly info. Otherwise there is just no guarantee that the type name is really the type you're looking for.

Comment: I think this gives me enough to go on, a combination of this and a custom JsonConverter on the dynamic property to force cast the type and it should work just fine, thanks!